# angularjs ng repeat svg skipping index of null values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, svg

I'm building a graph from the following datatype: points = [insulin:20, cho:30];.
Im using ng-repeat to loop through my array.
Im using the index as x-values and insulin or cho as y values. 
I want the index as x-values because later on I will use dates as x-value and want to display cho/insulin values if they occur on that date. **Values are bound to indices as they need to be shown at that timeframe in the svg**

```
<line class="insulinLine" ng-repeat="point in points | limitTo : 
points.length-1"
ng-x1="{{((width /points.length) * $index ) + (width/points.length)}}" 
ng-y1="{{((point.insulin / maxY) * 400)}}" 
ng-x2="{{((width / points.length) * ($index + 1)) + (width/points.length)}}" 
ng-y2="{{((points[$index + 1].insulin / maxY) * 400)}}"/>
```

My problem occurs at null values, if there is a null value i'd like ng-repeat to skip the index of y2 till the next non-null value so that the line is connected to the next actual value.

My tried options are:

1. do nothing, this sets the y value to the bottom of the graph
2. ng-if, not displaying null values will just not build the lines

   if="point.insulin!=null"
3. using ternary operators, messes up the whole graph, which is logical because it only evaluates at each point and doesn't move the index globally.

   points[$index + 1].insulin !== null ? ((points[$index + 1].insulin / maxY) * 400) : ((points[$index + 2].insulin / maxY) * 400)
4. You could put the x1,x2,y1,y2 values on each seperate point, using a function inside javascript to determine them for every line, but there should be an easier way?

Could you make a conditional where you look for the next non-null value and then use that and skip the index to that value?

codepen link:
https://codepen.io/mbezema/pen/bvWPVm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the points in javascript and constructing a new array does the trick. I then loop through the insulinLines and choLines arrays to set up the final lines. 
codepen link: https://codepen.io/mbezema/pen/bvWPVm

```
function determineLines() {
        var insulinStack = [];
        var choStack = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.points.length; i++) {
            if($scope.points[i].insulin !== null){
                console.log(i);
                insulinStack.push({
                    xValue: i,
                    insulin: $scope.points[i].insulin
                });
            }
            if($scope.points[i].cho !== null){
                choStack.push({
                    xValue: i,
                    cho: $scope.points[i].cho
                });
            }
        }
        $scope.insulinLines = [];
        $scope.choLines = [];
        while (insulinStack.length){
            $scope.insulinLines.push(insulinStack.pop());
        }
        while (choStack.length){
            $scope.choLines.push(choStack.pop());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just do this logic in the controller.
Have a setPoints methods, and each time you want to update the points array just go through that method.
Something like:

```
function ignoreNulls (array) {
    let lastValue = null;
    for (let i = array.length; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (!array[i]) {
            array[i] = lastValue;
        }
        else {
            lastValue = array[i];
        }
    }
}
```

What I am doing here, is going backwards in the array, checking if there is a value. If there is - cache it. If there isn't put the last cached value instead.

Comment: This wouldn't work as my values are bound to a date or index, so changing the value to the next non null value would create a horizontal line running along that non null value. So instead of connecting the line to the next index with a non null value it would create a straight line at all indexes with a non null value

Comment: The point is, do it in the controller not the ng-repeat. ngRepeat does not have that functionality.

Comment: yeah you could put the x1,x2,y1,y2 values on each seperate point, using a function inside javascript to determine them for every line, but there should be a smarter way? Ill try implementing this

Comment: you could try calling a method in the calculation of your points. but i strongly recommend against it as it will slow down your app. everything in ng-repeat happens on EACH render. so try to keep it as light as possible. doing a calculation one time before the rendering is much much better. 
because you are doing graphs i think efficiency is key here.

Comment: So then building a line array consisting of x1,x2,y1,y2 values and calculating all those once for your whole array of points would be preferable? Then filtering the range on the basis of which you would actually use

Comment: Yes, it would be better :)